# jQuery selector next after

Tags: jquery

people! I have a trouble...

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="track">1</div></li>
    <li><div class="track">2</div></li>
    <li><div class="track">3</div></li>
</ul>

<div class="track active">4</div>

<ul>
    <li><div class="track">5</div></li>
    <li><div class="track">6</div></li>
    <li><div class="track">7</div></li>
</ul>
```

How to select next element with class track in ALL document after element with classes track and active?

This is the jQuery that I tried, but it doesn't work.

```
$('.active').nextAll('.track').first(); $('.track.active').nextAll('.track').first();
```

Comment: Not working:
$('.active').nextAll('.track').first();
$('.track.active').nextAll('.track').first();

Comment: Demo: http://muzon.ws/test.html

Comment: `$('.active').closest('ul').next().find('.track:eq(0)')`?

Comment: many levels on DOM, not always ul and li. Can be:
<div class="track"></div>
<ul><li><div class="track"></div></li></ul>

Comment: It is going to be difficult.

Comment: i think that was be easy... maybe closest(document) or closest('body')?

Comment: Yes, but how will you get the next `.track` by getting `closest('body')`?

Comment: Post the jQuery code you have tried so far.

Comment: $('.track.active').closest('body').next('.track')
length = 0 :(
maybe because we found .track.active, then finding .track?

sorry for bad english :)

Comment: Please put that code in your original post to keep a good overview.

Comment: i think, found all .track and each array for next after .active - bad idea? or not?

Comment: I asked you to put the jQuery in your post, but you didn't do that. I did it for you. There are a couple of good answers now, make your pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Pq4J/1/)

```
$(function () {
        var n = $(".active").index(".track"),
            next = $(".track").eq(n+1);
    next.css({"color":"red"});
});
```

First get the index of the class active which also has class track. Then do that +1 and you have the index of the element you need.

While chrona's solution is legit as well, I think it uses too much resources (loop) for what you need here.

Comment: @user3265151 No problem. Please click the check mark below the down vote arrow to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all `.track`s and check if it is also `.active`, then store the result in a var and check it:

```
var active = false;

$('.track').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);

    if (active === true) {
        obj.css('background-color', 'red');
        active = false;
    }

    if (obj.hasClass('active')) {
       active = true;
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tWfc8/)

@Bram Vanroy's answer is much easier and doesn't need a loop, you should use his.

Comment: Good answer, but a bit overkill imo. + 1 nonetheless. See my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw it, I'd stick with your answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

It's uite tricky, but you can try with:

```
var tracks    = $('.track');
var nextTrack = tracks[tracks.index(tracks.filter('.active')) + 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.track').each(function(){

       if ($('.track').hasClass('active') == true) {
            $(this).next();//Do ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: This won't work, because `next()` only gets siblings.

Comment: And nice try to steal my `n+1`, but that won't work either because you haven't defined `n`.